# python help, d is not defined, highest to lowest

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a program which can print scores from 3 saved textfiles (X, Y & Z).

This is what I have so far

```
option = input("Do you want to review the scores in/from: A)Alphabetical order with highest score. B) Highest-lowest. C)Average from highest-lowest. D)Top 3 scores. [A/B/C/D]? : ") 

if option == 'C':
    def read_scores(scorefile):
        with open(scorefile, 'r') as f:
               d = {}
               averages =[]
    for name, v in d.items():
        average = (sum(v)/len(v))
        averages.append((name, average))
    for name, average in sorted(averages, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
        print(name, average)
        for scorefile in ['Class X.txt', 'Class Y.txt', 'Class Z.txt']:
            if Class == "X":
                read_scores('Class X.txt')
            elif Class == "Y":
                read_scores('Class Y.txt')
            elif Class == "Z":
                    read_scores('Class Z.txt')'
```

The problem is that I have tried to adjust this piece of coding so that it can allow me to print the highest to lowest scores from each textfile, but the same error of 'd' no being defined occurs, can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, it would be amazing if you could.

Also, this is how each score is set out in each text file -

Oliver : 2

and the each score that is saved in the textfile is out of 10.

I am using Python version 3.3.2.

Comment: `d` is not defined when you first attempt to use it (at `for name, v in d.items():`). You declare it in the function `read_scores` but hadn't yet called that function.

Comment: Also, `read_scores` opens the file as `f` but never uses the variable `f` again.

Answer (score 1):

```
def read_scores(scorefile):
    with open(scorefile, 'r') as f:
           d = {}
           averages =[]
```

only *defines* the function `read_scores()` - unless you also *call*  it, `d` is in fact undefined, so the next line produces the error message you mentioned.

Then, you're not actually doing anything in that function - for example, you never read anything from the file, so `d` will still be an empty dictionary at the end of the function.

Finally, `d` and `averages` are local variables to the function, so even if you did do something with them, they would be discared when the function is exited, so you'd at least need to `return` them.